# How to refer to home directory when calling external script from vim in windows

Tags: windows, vim

I'm trying to setup use of `vim-plug` to manage my vim plugins.
Therefore I added this to my `.vimrc` file:

```
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
```

This should download the `plug-vim` script to the `autoload` folder when it does not exist yet.

This works perfectly on Mac/Linux, but it doesn't on Windows. The problem seems to be that `~` is not known on Windows, so the `curl` command just creates a new folder with the name `~`.

I tried

```
silent !curl -fLo $HOME/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

but this did not work.

I tried

```
  silent !curl -fLo "%HOME%/.vim/autoload/plug.vim" --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

but this also did not work. I got this error message:

```
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h":
```

Note that the `%HOME%` environment variable is defined on my system.

Of course I know that I can install the `plug.vim` script manually before first use, but I still like to know:

**How can I pass the `user home` directory when calling an external command from within vim on Windows?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HOME` is an environment variable coming from Unix (though Vim on Windows picks it up if it's defined). The corresponding Windows variable is the concatenation of `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`; these should be defined for you (check with `set HOME` in a Windows command prompt).

As you use the `:!` command, special characters (i.e. `:help filename-modifiers` like `%`) need escaping; you can use the `shellescape()` function. Be sure to set the `{special}` argument to `1` (or switch to `:call system()` instead):

```
execute 'silent !curl -fLo' shellescape("%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.vim/autoload/plug.vim", 1)  '--create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim'
```

Note that the default name of `.vim` is `vimfiles` on Windows; you probably have custom code in your `~/.vimrc` that manipulates `'runtimepath'` so that `.vim` is used on Windows as well; else this would need to be changed, too.

Comment: Actually, `%HOME%` is defined on my system, so your solution is equivalent to my second attempt... and it doesn't work either... I'll edit my post with error message

Comment: Ah, that error message helps! We forgot the escaping; in a command-line, `%` refers to the current file. Please see my edit.

Comment: Great, this did it! Thanks
(BTW, I' have indeed code in `~/.vimrc` that manipulates `'runtimepath'` so that `.vim` is used on Windows as well

Comment: Ah great! Yes, I do that as well, in order to easily synchronize my Vim configuration between different systems.

Answer (score 2):

For a portable solution, I would have used

```
 shellescape(fnamemodify('~', ':p'))
```

Vim knows how to translate `~`.

Comment: I actually like this, because I like it to be portable to be used on Windows/Mac/Linux!